# LDAP - Sitecore: Missing or Empty connection string

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am using the [online-ldap-test-server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) for integrating with Sitecore 8.1 for testing purposes. The configurations that I have done for it are as below:

Connection String:`<add name="ADConnString" connectionString="LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/OU=scientists,DC=example,DC=com"/>`

Providers:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ad" type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnString" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" connectionUsername="" connectionPassword="" connectionProtection="Secure" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="switcher" providerWildcard="%"
      raiseEvents="true"/>
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256"/>
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore"
      mappings="switchingProviders/membership"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="sitecore" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ad" type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnString" applicationName="sitecore" username="" password=""  attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" cacheSize="2MB" />    
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreRoleProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="switcher" raiseEvents="true"/>
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore"/>
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingRoleProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore"
      mappings="switchingProviders/roleManager"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile defaultProvider="sitecore" enabled="true" inherits="Sitecore.Security.UserProfile, Sitecore.Kernel">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ad" type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADProfileProvider" connectionstringname="ADConnString" applicationname="sitecore" username="" password="" sitecoremapdomainname="ad"></add>
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreRoleProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="switcher" raiseEvents="true" />
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore"/>
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingProfileProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore"
      mappings="switchingProviders/profile"/>
  </providers>
```

Switching Providers:

```
<switchingProviders>
<membership>
  <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*"/>
  <provider providerName="ad" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="*" domains="ad" />
</membership>
<roleManager>
  <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" ignoredUserDomains="" allowedUserDomains=""/>
  <provider providerName="ad" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="*" domains="ad" />
</roleManager>
<profile>
  <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" ignoredDomains=""/>
  <provider providerName="ad" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="*" domains="ad" />
</profile>
```

Domains.config

```
<domain name="ad" ensureAnonymousUser="false"/>
```

But I am getting an error which states "Missing or Empty connection string". I get this error only if I add the entries for Profile providers under switchingproviders and providers sections. Please refer the screen shot shown below for details:

[Missing or Empty Connection String Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ebs.jpg)

And when I comment the Profile providers entries, although I don't get this error and my domains's membership, role providers seems to be on (in admin/providerstatus.aspx) , but I am not able login using the AD users.
Any help in this regard is appreciated. Additionally, does mongoDb play any role for LDAP Sitecore integration to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but it seems that you have all parameters in lower case in the profile provider definition. Please try with the correct casing.

Regarding MongoDB, MongoDB is not needed for LDAP to work.

Comment: Thanks Lars for pointing that out, somehow I completely missed the correct case. Although, I am still unable to login using the AD users or see any users in the user manager. Do you see anything which I am missing out here? Any help in this regard is well appreciated.

Comment: How do you authenticate with the AD? You have empty parameters in the membership provider definition (connectionUsername="" connectionPassword="") - please remove these and see what happens.

Next step would be to consult the Event Log and see if it gives you any hints.